# WPF: Binding UserControl inside ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, itemscontrol

I'm tryin to make some wpf, which displays my user control for every day of some date range. So far ive tryied datagrid, but it does not support different data type of rows, so I'm tryin to solve it by UserControl and ItemsControl.

My UserControl - PeriodDayControl.xaml looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp.PeriodDayControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="168.443" Width="104.098">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="20,10,21,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=price}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="31,61,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=check}"  Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="42,117,0,0" Height="16" Width="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.372,0.449"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And code to register properties for binding (PeriodDayControl.xaml.cs):

```
        public PeriodDayControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string name
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(nameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(nameProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty nameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("name", typeof(string), typeof(PeriodDayControl));

        public decimal price
        {
            get { return (decimal)GetValue(priceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(priceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty priceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("price", typeof(decimal), typeof(PeriodDayControl));

        public bool check
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(checkProperty); }
            set { SetValue(checkProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty checkProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("check", typeof(bool), typeof(PeriodDayControl));
```

So it look's like this in designer:
[image]

In MainWindow.xaml I'm trying to use Items control, to create template:

```
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlMain" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}" Margin="0,166,0,0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:PeriodDayControl name="{Binding Path=nameProperty}" price="{Binding Path=priceProperty}" check="{Binding Path=checkProperty}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

and here is my try to create and populate data to PeriodDayControl:

```
            List<PeriodDayControl> pdcList = new List<PeriodDayControl>();
            pdcList.Add(new PeriodDayControl() { name = "01/01",price =(decimal)55, check=true});
            pdcList.Add(new PeriodDayControl() { name = "02/01",price =(decimal)55, check=false});
            pdcList.Add(new PeriodDayControl() { name = "03/01",price =(decimal)55, check=true});
            ObservableCollection<PeriodDayControl> pdcColl = new ObservableCollection<PeriodDayControl>(pdcList);
            ItemsControlMain.ItemsSource = pdcColl;
```

Here is how it looks now:
[image]

And finally here is what I'm trying to achive:
[image]

Right now it shows:
[image]

And here are my questions. Is it right decision to use ItemsControl? Or are there any other posibilities, to achive such funcionality? What's wrong with this solution(why it does not populate data)? To make context, I would like to change checkbox/price and then press button , which will read data from all of UserControl and save it to db.
**Thank you for any advice.**

Comment: It makes no sense to have an ItemTemplate with a PeriodDayControl when the item is already a PeriodDayControl. You do typically not use UI elements as data items. The ItemsSource should instead hold a collection of instances of a data item class that exposes the source properties of the bindings in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: As a note, consider using Pascal casing for property names, i.e. names with an uppercase first character. That is a widely accepted convention.

Comment: @VojtechMach: What is `{Binding ViewModels}` supposed to bind to?

Comment: Hello guys, the problem was, as Clemens said, I added UI elements inside datatemplate, instead of it I created class with properties as name, price,... and added it to ObservableCollection, then sets ItemsSource of my ItemsControl. As you already noticed, there are many programming languages, where we don't use Pascal casing 
 but its not part of Q.

Comment: @mm8: I Thought I could bind the ItemsSource throught xaml Binding, but I think I completly missing something, since I couldn't make it work. (And didn't delete here in the post.) Here it could be "{Binding pdcColl}" ? But it does not work either. 
Thank you all for your comments.